# CSS and JS not loading after uploading onto server

Tags: errors, directory, server, ftp

(Pretty new to WP/coding, sorry if I'm asking a weird question)
Here's the problem:
Had a local WP-project (using WAMP) uploaded via FTP (Filezilla) on W3W (host), but it get's me a

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED>
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()>

error for all the files, leaving only the HTML left to be shown.
I'm also using Elementor (plugin) for the design of the pages - if that is of importance.
I was thinking that it might be because of some wrong directories, but i don't know where to look ...
Anyone out there that knows what it might be?

Comment: Are you getting this error from FTP or from trying to visit the website?

Comment: When trying to visit the website

Comment: 500 errors usually indicate an issue with the code or server. I recommending setting `WP_DEBUG` to true to see if there's a reported error for these urls. If it's not the WordPress code, it could be a problem with the server configuration.

Comment: thanks for the input!  
`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
sounds like i got a problem with the config ... will keep you updated!

Comment: That's an error with connecting to the database. You need to change the connection details in `wp-config.php` to match those of your host. Good luck!